# C++ 64 bit multiplication giving 128 bit number

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand what's the difference between these 2 macros:

```
#define SEAL_MULTIPLY_UINT64_HW64(operand1, operand2, hw64)                                 \
    do                                                                                      \
    {                                                                                       \
        *hw64 = static_cast<unsigned long long>(                                            \
            ((static_cast<uint128_t>(operand1) * static_cast<uint128_t>(operand2)) >> 64)); \
    } while (false);

#define SEAL_MULTIPLY_UINT64(operand1, operand2, result128)              \
    do                                                                   \
    {                                                                    \
        uint128_t product = static_cast<uint128_t>(operand1) * operand2; \
        result128[0] = static_cast<unsigned long long>(product);         \
        result128[1] = static_cast<unsigned long long>(product >> 64);   \
    } while (false)
```

Why the first one does >> 64 on the entire prouct but the second one does only for the second part?

Comment: `_HW64` == "High Word (64 bits)", probably.

Comment: I don't know C++ 64-bit multiplication but it seems to me that those 2 macros do not compute the same thing. In the first case, it seems that the result (written to `hw64`) cares about only the most significant 64-bit. In the second case, `result128` may hold the entire result, `result128[0]` being the least significant 64 bits (implicitely truncated), and `result128[1]` hold the higher bits.

Comment: The first one doesn't need to cast on `operand2`, and has a subtle problem with that last semicolon (after the `while`).

Answer (score 0):

> Why the first one does >> 64 on the entire prouct but the second one does only for the second part?

They both do it on the full product, but the first macro only stores the upper 64 bits, rather than the entire 128 bits.

Since they're the same, you could reuse the first macro in the second macro (this would be silly though, since you'd be multiplying twice):

```
#define SEAL_MULTIPLY_UINT64(operand1, operand2, result128)              \
    do                                                                   \
    {                                                                    \
        uint128_t product = static_cast<uint128_t>(operand1) * operand2; \
        result128[0] = static_cast<unsigned long long>(product);         \
        SEAL_MULTIPLY_UINT64_HW64(operand1, operand2, &result128[1])     \
    } while (false)
```

The first one could be something like what you'd want to do with [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) multiplication. The result of fixed point multiplication is up in the high 64 bits of 128bit output, so (for the sake of keeping the result 64 bits long) you'd only want to save the upper bits.